# three.js - tube geometry scaling

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, three.js

I've a tube geometry built with 200 points and it has bend at many portions.
Now I am showing a portion with +/- 10 points where user double-clicks on a tube. 
The selected portions is scaled by `tubeMesh.scale.x` and `tubeMesh.scale.z`.
If user clicks on a cylindrical portion, the scaled tube appears good.

But the issue is with the portion where there is a bend on a tube. The scaled tube does not appear good. Please have a look at attached image.[image: bend portion in a scaled view]

**How do I scaled the tube so that it looks perfect whatever the portion is selected ?**

Answer (score 0):

Scale according to the boundingbox if the bounding box is small at 1 side then have a bigger scale then.

```
tubeMesh.computeBoundingBox();
tubeMesh.scale.x = 100 / (tubeMesh.boundingBox.max.x - tubeMesh.boundingBox.min.x);
tubeMesh.scale.z = 100 / (tubeMesh.boundingBox.max.z - tubeMesh.boundingBox.min.z);
```

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code ? As I am not computing bounding box:@Gero3

Comment: Thanks for the code. Facing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined` in three.js r54.@Gero3